# Get length of String

Tags: xpath

Dear Users,

```
 <note>
    <to>ToText</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
 </note>
```

I am in need to get the string length of `XML` tag using `Xpath`. I am using `string-lenth()`, but not able to render exact result.

Is there a way to get `string-lenght(/to)` or  `string-lenght(/from)`?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use below `XPath`:

```
//from/string-length(text())
```

or

```
//to/string-length(text())
```

Comment: If the document structure is known, `//` should be avoided. Your suggestions only work in XPath 2.0. In XPath 1.0, functions cannot be axis steps and the expression would have to be `string-length(/note/to)`, for instance.

Comment: @宏杰李 `XPath` version is not mentioned in question. You could provide solution applicable to `1.0` version

Answer (score 1):

Mathias Muller is correct, this should work:
`string-length(/note/to)` or `string-length(/note/from)`

please check your spelling of length as well.....